# Swift: sorting function for ordering paths (needs to be fast!)

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, path, tree

**NOTE: I found a way to do what I'm looking for, the code is below. I need to optimize it as much as possible now because the execution is still taking 20+ seconds on an array with 8k objects**

I want to sort an `Array` of objects having a `path` property and representing files on the user's system. What I want to achieve is the following:

Consider this directory structure

```
├── a
│   └── a.ext
├── b
│   ├── b.ext
│   ├── c.ext
│   └── d
│       └── d.ext
├── c
│   └── e.ext
├── f.ext
└── g.ext
```

When reading the content of the directory with NSFileManager, I get the paths in an order that's not the one I want. Therefore, I need to sort the array to get the order:

```
./f.ext
./g.ext
./a/a.ext
./b/b.ext
./b/c.ext
./b/d/d.ext
./c/e.ext
```

The ordering should be **case insensitive**. For every folder, files are displayed first in alphabetical order, then folders are presented, and in each of these folders the same rules apply.

Is there a way to sort an array to get the desired order? What does the sort function look like?

Thanks!

**EDIT**:

I found a solution myself, but I'm now wondering if it can be sped up?

```
    func sorter(obj1: FilesListData, obj2: FilesListData) -> Bool {
        var result: Bool = false

        let url1 = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: obj1.path)
        let url2 = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: obj2.path)
        guard let c1 = url1.pathComponents else {
            return result
        }
        guard let c2 = url2.pathComponents else {
            return result
        }

        for i in 0..<min(c1.count, c2.count) {
            if c1[i] == c2[i] {
                continue
            } else {
                if i+1 == c1.count {
                    if i+1 == c2.count {
                        result = c1[i].lowercaseString < c2[i].lowercaseString
                        break
                    } else {
                        result = true
                        break
                    }
                } else {
                    if i+1 == c2.count {
                        result = false
                        break
                    } else {
                        result = c1[i].lowercaseString < c2[i].lowercaseString
                        break
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return asc ? result : !result //asc is a variable indicating if the order should be ascending or not
    }
```

Comment: I think you need to expand your use of NSURL components and wrap your entires in a class with a custom comparator. Additionally some sorts do just take time to complete. You can speed it up by using something like a bubble sort on your insertion but comparing strings always kind of sucks. I'm not sure what optimizations you'll get for sorting for free either.

Comment: I added some code in my question, that should help get the optimization discussion started ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a concise way to do it that I believe should be quick enough:

[EDIT: adjusted to show how to use it with an object list]

```
class FileObject
{
   var path:String
   init(_ path:String)
   { self.path = path }
}

var files:[FileObject] = 
  [
    FileObject("./b/c.ext"),
    FileObject("./f.ext"),
    FileObject("./g.ext"),
    FileObject("./a/a.ext"),
    FileObject("./b/b.ext"),
    FileObject("./b/d/d.ext"),
    FileObject("./c/e.ext")
  ]

files = files.map({ ($0, $0.path.rangeOfString("/", options: .BackwardsSearch)!) })
             .map({ ($0, $0.path.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange($1, withString: "/ ")) })
             .map({ ($0, $1.lowercaseString) })
             .sort({ $0.1 < $1.1 })
             .map({  $0.0 })


files.forEach({ print($0.path) })

// prints:
//
// ./f.ext
// ./g.ext
// ./a/a.ext
// ./b/b.ext
// ./b/c.ext
// ./b/d/d.ext
// ./c/e.ext

// Benchmark for 8000 gives 0.134 sec.
```

Comment: YES! Oh my god this is super fast and so concise, exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much!

Comment: Note: If you need to add to the array and resort it often, you could make this even faster by storing a "sortString" in your class (built using the same 3 operations as the .map calls in my example) and the use a simple sort($0.sortString < $1.sortString) to resort the array.

Comment: Wonderful idea, but according to my tests the whole sorting thing takes pretty much the same time as a simple sort (in production, I didn't try in XCTest) I noticed the Swift compiler sometimes has trouble with the short version of `map` and `sort` so I rewrote everything with long-form closures, including argument and return types

Answer (score 1):

Does this help? Usage:

```
printContents("/Users/paulvs/Desktop/my directory")
```

Code:

```
func printContents(path: String) {
    let fileManager = NSFileManager()
    let URL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)
    let keys = [NSURLIsDirectoryKey]
    let enumerator = fileManager.enumeratorAtURL(URL, includingPropertiesForKeys: keys, options: NSDirectoryEnumerationOptions(rawValue: 0), errorHandler: { url, error -> Bool in
        return true
    })!

    var filePaths = [String]()
    var directoryPaths = [String]()

    while let url = enumerator.nextObject() as? NSURL {
        var path: AnyObject?
        var isDirectory: AnyObject?
        do {
            try url.getResourceValue(&isDirectory, forKey: NSURLIsDirectoryKey)
            try url.getResourceValue(&path, forKey: NSURLPathKey)

            if isDirectory as? Bool == true {
                directoryPaths.append(path as! String)
                enumerator.skipDescendants()
            } else {
                filePaths.append(path as! String)
            }
        } catch _ {

        }
    }

    filePaths.sort().forEach({ filePath in
        print(filePath)
    })

    directoryPaths.sort().forEach({ directoryPath in
        printContents(directoryPath)
    })
}
```

Comment: This could help but is it faster than what I proposed in my edited question? With this method, I would have to assign an ID to each file in the order that it is read and then sort upon that ID because the order the of Array can change over time. I need to be able to sort it several times during its life time.

Comment: You could benchmark your code with XCTest and compare it.

Comment: Okay after some benchmarking this method is pretty fast but it doesn't really do what I was asking in the question: sort an array of objects which have a path property (String)

Comment: I understand that it was not precisely answering what you are asking, but since you are using`NSFileManager` I figured you could do the sort as you read the paths.

Comment: You're right, this would help for the first reading. The thing is, the array is then displayed in a table view, and the filenames can change over the course of the program execution. I want to be able to re-sort the table (array) when a file is renamed without re-reading all the files from the filesytem. Also, users can choose to sort the table though another column, and when they want to sort it back against path, I need to be able to re-sort the array too. Thanks anyway I'm keeping this code for later use/optimization!

Answer (score 0):

So you want to sort your paths by the outermost directory as the first sort key, then the next inner directory as the 2nd sort key, down to the filename as the last sort key (where no directory at any level sorts to the top)?

If you only have a single directory in the mix this would be dirt simple. Get the directory. Get the filename. Create a sort descriptor that sorts using those 2 as sort keys. If you need to handle deeper directory structures it gets a little more complicated.

Comment: The rules I could devise go like this: look at the first path component of each of the two files to compare, 1. if they are equal, go on to look at the next path component and start over, 2. if they are different then (2.1 if both components represent files, sort alphabetically, 2.2 if one component is a file and the other a dir, file goes first, 2.3 if both are folder components, sort alphabetically). I posted some code in my question, we need to optimize it! ;)